# Unable to install packages through home-brew

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I am tring to install new packages like keras, gnuplot or tensor flow. But my home-brew keeps giving me an error and I am unable to figure out what is wrong exactly.

I have already tried upgrading home-brew and a lot of other functions. But they just don't seem to work. I am pretty new to UNIX, and hence, I am not familiar with most of these errors.

Do let me know what I can do to get this problem solved.

If I type : `brew install gnuplot`
I get this:

```
portable-ruby/2.3.3_2/share/man/man1/ri.1: Failed to create dir 'portable-ruby/2.3.3_2'Can't create 'portable-ruby/2.3.3_2/share/man/man1/ri.1'
portable-ruby/2.3.3_2/share/man/man1/ruby.1: Failed to create dir 'portable-ruby/2.3.3_2'Can't create 'portable-ruby/2.3.3_2/share/man/man1/ruby.1'
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Error: Failed to upgrade vendor ruby.
Error: Failed to upgrade vendor Ruby.
Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Cannot save the current index state
Error: Could not 'git stash' in /usr/local/Homebrew!
Please stash/commit manually if you need to keep your changes or, if not, run:
  cd /usr/local/Homebrew
  git reset --hard origin/master
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- dbm (LoadError)
```

Comment: Try running brew doctor to see if it will return any helpful debugging information. I'm not sure it will help but its worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Brew Doctor and then Brew upgrade. This should fix your problems and you could be able to install it correctly.